# What does "rebuttal to termination" mean?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I read this sentense

> She didn't show up to hear her **rebuttal to termination**.

So I need to handle the final task for termination of her.

What is **rebuttal to termination**? Does it mean that the employee is angry and mad for this decision because he/she believes it is unfair?

Answer (score 1):

A **rebuttal** is a counter-argument. An argument for a particular opinion is made, a person that disagrees may offer a rebuttal, that is an reasoned case for disagreeing with the opinion and argument supporting it. There is no intrinsic reason why in such an exchange there should be anger. There need not be strong emotions when formulating a rebuttal, but I suppose in practice there often will be.

In this case the opinion in question was a decision to terminate, we don't see all the context here, but I'm inferring someone's employment is to be terminated. A rebuttal of termination, would be to offer an argument as to why termination should not happen. This could happen at a formal meeting or **hearing**.

The phrasing here: "hear her rebuttal to termination" seems a little odd to me. I would have expected "**offer** her rebuttal". It seems that the overall meaning is that as the person in question did not challenge the termination the speaker is to complete the termination process.

Comment: "I would have expected "offer her rebuttal" - may it be that  she (employer) didn't show up to hear her (employee's) rebuttal to termination?

Comment: @Rompey: Agreed that we don't know for sure that "She" and "Her" refer to the same person, but I'm not convinced that the employer failing to turn up to hear a rebuttal would lead to the termination proceeding, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: I see. Should the rebuttal of termination be established by employer?

Comment: The text in question doesn't give us the details of the situation. I'm making inferences from my general business experience. An employer may choose to terminate a person's employment. In large organisations there may be a formal process for such termination where the employer must set out the reasons for the termination. The process may then permit the employee to offer counter-argument (rebuttal) as to why the termination should not proceed. So in that situation it is the employee who offers the rebuttal.